# Is there a way to generate barcode image from text in cpp?

Tags: c++, image, barcode

I have a code that generates barcode number in CPP and in order to display it in the receipt, I need to convert that number to an Image(.bmp).

Is there an existing library or a way to achieve the above result?

Comment: Can you not use SDL to create your barcode as a bmp?

Comment: Look up the definition for how barcodes are generated, use that to write pixel data to a buffer in memory and then use https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h to write it to disk.

Comment: What type of barcode do you wish to implement?

Comment: look at this C++ Barcode Processing API https://products.aspose.com/barcode/cpp

Answer (score 0):

Here's some snippets of code that I used for generating an Interleaved 2 of 5 barcode, the easiest 1D barcode.
It's only set for numbers and not letters, but I'm sure that you'll get the drift.

This dictates the line spacing for numbers 0 to 9 inclusive

```
const char I25_Code[10][6] = { {"NNWWN"}, {"WNNNW"}, {"NWNNW"}, {"WWNNN"}, {"NNWNW"}, {"WNWNN"}, {"NWWNN"}, {"NNNWW"}, {"WNNWN"}, {"NWNWN"} };
```

This generates generates the barcode:

```
void GenerateBarcodeI2of5(unsigned int startX, unsigned int startY, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, char *value)
{
    if(value==NULL)return;

    if(strlen(stringbuffer)==0) return;

    int minBarThickness = MIN_BARCODE_BAR_WIDTH;
    int barRatio = BARCODE_BAR_RATIO_3_TO_1 ? 3:2;

    bool bars = true;
    int sl = strlen(stringbuffer);
    int pixelX=0;
    pixelX=startX;
    for(int i=0;i<sl;i++)
    {
        char c = stringbuffer[i];
        if(bars)
        {
            if(c=='N' || c=='n')
            {
                GenerateLine(pixelX, startY, minBarThickness, height, false);
                pixelX+=minBarThickness;
            }
            else
            {
                GenerateLine(pixelX, startY, minBarThickness*barRatio, height, false);
                pixelX+=minBarThickness*barRatio;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(c=='N' || c=='n')
            {
                GenerateLine(pixelX, startY, minBarThickness, height, true);
                pixelX+=minBarThickness;
            }
            else
            {
                GenerateLine(pixelX, startY, minBarThickness*barRatio, height, true);
                pixelX+=minBarThickness*barRatio;                       
            }
        }
        bars=!bars;
    }
}
```

The premise here is that there is a byte array that represents the bitmap and sub-functions set the bits within that byte array e.g. SetPixel.

```
void GenerateLine(unsigned int startX, unsigned int startY, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, bool inverse)
{
    int bit = inverse?0:1;
    for(int x = startX; x<(width+startX); x++)
    {
        for(int y=startY; y<(startY+height); y++)
        {
            if(x>=IMAGE_COLUMNS) continue;
            if(y>=IMAGE_ROWS) continue;
            SetPixel(x,y,ScreenImageData,IMAGE_ARRAY_COLUMN_DATA_BYTES, bit);
        }
    }
}
```